# How to prevent Anti-pattern: Unconditionally copying props to state in below case

Tags: reactjs

I have a products page generating a list from the response from service.
The response have this form

```
    [
    {name: P1,
    color:c1},
    {name: P2,
    color:c2},
    {name: P3,
    color:c3},
    {name: P4,
    color:c4}
    ]
```

I want to compare products on the next page (say compare page). On compare, page user can add (max 4)/change selected products from the dropdown. So from "products page" I am sending data as below

```
this.props.history.push('/compareproduct', {
    products: this.state.products,
    productsToCompare, // In form of [{name: P1, color:c1}, {name: P4, color:c4}]
  });
```

Is there any other way to set state? As this is an anti-pattern.

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {productsToCompare: this.props.localtion.state.productsToCompare}
}
```

In routes

```
<Route path="/products" component={products} />
<Route path="/compareproducts" component={CompareProducts} />
```

Comment: Why do you need that data in state? Just compare the data getting passed down via props... Or I have misunderstood what you are trying to do

Comment: Can't move data down as they are in different components.
<Route
      path="/products"
      component={products}
    />
<Route path="/compareproducts" component={CompareProducts} />

Comment: Are you using `redux` also? Just set `productsToCompare` to a reducer state and get from it inside your `CompareProducts` component

Comment: No, I am not using redux.

Comment: You need to move your data up a component into a logic container or something.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments in your qn, wherein the situation is such that the compare product is not a child of the products component, I think the most straightforward way to implement this would be via the Context API.

1-Create a `Context.jsx` component

```
// export default ContextProvider;
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export const AppContext = React.createContext();

class ContextProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        productsToCompare: [],
    };

    updateProductsToCompare = newProducts => {
        // Logic to update the state here from your Products Page
        this.setState({ productsToCompare: newProducts });
    };
    render() {
        const { productsToCompare } = this.state;
        return (
            <AppContext.Provider value={{ productsToCompare, updateProductsToCompare: this.updateProductsToCompare }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </AppContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default ContextProvider;
```

2-Wrap your  or root component in ContextProvider (imported by above component)
3-In your '/products' page:

```
<AppContext.Consumer>
    {({ updateProductsToCompare }) => (
        <div>Component here. Use function to update state in context</div>
    )}
</AppContext.Consumer>
```

4-In your '/compare' page: Do the same as above, but compare the products

```
<AppContext.Consumer>
    {({ productsToCompare }) => (
        <div>Component here. Use products to compare stored in context</div>
    )}
</AppContext.Consumer>
```